# What's an Oedipus word?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Oedipus Word™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Oedipus Words™ | Not Oedipus Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| FICTION | REALITY |
| AMERICA | FRANCE |
| JUNGLE | FOREST |
| PATRIOT | BRONCO |
| BROWN | YELLOW |
| PLANE | BOAT |
| REVENGE | MERCY |
| VIOLIN | BASS |
| SEVEN | SIX |
| EIGHT | NINE |
| ROMANCE | FRIENDSHIP |

CSV version:

```
Oedipus Words™, Not Oedipus Words™

Fiction,        Reality
America,        France
Jungle,         Forest
Patriot,        Bronco
Brown,          Yellow
Plane,          Boat
Revenge,        Mercy
Violin,         Bass
Seven,          Six
Eight,          Nine
Romance,        Friendship
```

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Oedipus Word is

> any word that appears in the title of a film in which Samuel L. Jackson has appeared.

Going through the ones in the question:

> `FICTION:  Pulp Fiction`
>  `AMERICA:  Coming to America`
>  `JUNGLE:   Jungle Fever`
>  `PATRIOT:  Patriot Games`
>  `BROWN:    Jackie Brown`
>  `PLANE:    Snakes on a Plane`
>  `REVENGE:  Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith`
>  `VIOLIN:   The Red Violin`
>  `SEVEN:    One Eight Seven`
>  `EIGHT:    The Hateful Eight`
>  `ROMANCE:  True Romance`

These are called Oedipus words because

> Samuel L. Jackson is famous for saying "motherf**ker", which is what Oedipus was (credit to hexomino for making the connection).

Comment: That's the one! And indeed there was a typo in america that I'll fix